# Is there any more information about the additional female Death Eaters in the movies?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, death-eaters

As mentioned in the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/164234/were-there-any-female-death-eaters-other-than-bellatrix-and-alecto-carrow-in-the), there were only two known female Death Eaters who were described in the books. In the movies, there are at least four different women with the Death Eaters who aren’t either Bellatrix or Alecto Carrow, seen in the pictures below. Is anything more ever mentioned about these women? For example, are they ever given names in the end credits, or given any backstory or details in any source, either in or out of universe?

**Is anything else known about the additional female Death Eaters in the movies?**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn't Malfoy's mother the person who claims that Harry is dead in the finale of book 7?

Comment: Ok, I read the other question now. Are you sure that all the people in those pictures are actual death eaters?

Comment: @Fabian Yes, but she’s not actually a Death Eater. Also, no, I’m not sure - it’s possible the other women are “allies” like Narcissa. I’m hoping for more information either way - though I am hoping they’re actually Death Eaters. It would be so disappointing if the Dark Lord was resistant to letting women join the Death Eaters.

Comment: Sure, mass murderer and racist is ok, but sexism goes too far.

Comment: @Fabian The girl behind this account likes Bellatrix, and would be disappointed if she couldn’t join the same group as her idol, that’s all. ;)

Comment: We know quite a lot about the one in the foreground of the first photo. Height, country of origin, fondness for flesheating, the lot.

Comment: Scoping out the competition, eh?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet No, trying to find fellow women among the Death Eater ranks! :)

Comment: Ty for the bounty. I'm glad you liked your answer!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

None of them seem to have names in the credits. They're just billed as "Death Eater/s"

**Goblet of Fire**
[image]

**Deathly Hallows, Pt I**
[image]

**Deathly Hallows, Pt II**
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! :) I figured they probably wouldn’t have names, but I decided to try asking anyway. The credits prove they are actually Death Eaters, too, thanks! :D

Comment: What did Penelope McGhie do to merit being called 'Death Eater' rather than 'Death Eaters', I wonder...

Comment: The credits were *in order of appearance*. The other three appeared at the same time. She appeared separately in the background during an earlier scene (along with some other death eaters who'd already appeared even earlier in the film).

Comment: Is *Ashley* not a girl's name anymore?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - Traditionally male, but largely unisex for the past 80 years, at least in the UK and US

Answer (score 1):

Well we don't know anything about them, but I would think that their being credited as Death Eaters proves that Voldemort has no problem employing females. He even wanted the muggle-born woman Lily Potter to join his cause! As I've mentioned in another topic, we probably don't even know the names of half of the Death Eaters in the books so odds are there are many female Death Eaters that Harry never meets, notices, or are mentioned to him. I wish JK Rowling would've written in a few more of them.

I've looked in the credits and found a good number of actresses credited as Death Eaters: Catherine Balavage, Judith Sharp, Ashley McGuire, Penelope McGhie, Chloe Franks, Serena Catapano, Elizabeth Jee, Natalie Hallam, Olivia Higginbottom, Elisabeth Roberts.

I got these names from Harry Potter Wiki on both Deathly Hallows film pages. There may be more I missed.

Comment: Maybe you could consider adding in a source to the credits list where you found the names? This would help the user base judge your answer as objectively correct and provide evidence for you claims